# Mail app, Flagged count always wrong

Tags: mail.app, email, spotlight, exchange

I have a problem with the Mail app. It always shows the wrong count after using it for a while. I already reset my spotlight index and also did the "Rebuild" in the app.

As an example below, it says "2" but no mail is marked (0 would be the right value)

[image]

Any suggestions?
I use outlook.com as a mail provider.

Comment: Have you tried restarting?  Also, take a look at the Microsoft Outlook app - I’ve found it much, much stronger than Apple’s Mail app.

Answer (score 2):

**Tip**: you can go to any folder accessible from your Mac by hitting `cmd+shift+G` on your keyboard (whilst being in Finder)

According to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/379761/262710) you can do the following:

• Quit Mail if it’s open.

• In `~/Library/Mail/V7/MailData`, delete any file that begins with “Envelope Index,” such as Envelope Index or Envelope Index-shm.

• Your home Library folder is hidden by default. To display it, choose Finder > “Go to Folder” and then enter `~/Library`

• Open Mail.

• Mail creates new Envelope Index files. This process may take a few minutes, depending on how many messages Mail is reindexing.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to edit manually FlagMailboxes.plist (located in ~/Library/Mail/V7/Maildata) with textedit or any other text editor.

Look for 1 and replace 1 or your incorrect number with 0 or the number you need.

Comment: This did not work. As soon as Mail was restarted FlagMailboxes.plist was automatically updated back to the original incorrect values. However the [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/379761/262710) referenced by @van did work.